# Find the probability density function of random variable Z when it is given as a function of X and Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Random variables X and Y are **independant** and **distributed normally** so that $ X \sim N(0,2) $ and $ Y \sim N(0,2)$. If a new random variable Z is defined as $  Z = {X \over Y}$, find $ f_z(z) $ and $  F_Z (z)$.

Comment: 56 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is at this link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution

The derivation is found here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation